# JQuery Validation Triggering on Failure

Tags: jquery, 4d-database

OK, I have been trying for days to do something that feels like it should be very simple.  Basically I have a form setup.  It currently is required to check for an email address within a 4d database, and if it exist post a message that states that this email address already exist.  I am trying to create something that opens a dialog box when this occurs.  So basically when the stipulation for the required email address fails, the dialog box should open.

Is there some sort of way using JQuery UI to have something like this occur when something occurs on success or failure of a single field entry? If someone can simply point me in the right direction it would be a great help.

This is the dialog box.

```
$( "#emailDuplicateDialog" ).dialog({
resizable: false,
height:140,
width: 575,
modal: true,
    buttons: {
"Go to Login Page": function () {
$(this).dialog("close");
location = "Login.a4d"
},
}
```

Here is the code, this is based on a Jquerytools version that I would like to scrap simply because I cannot for the life of me get it to function, and am looking for an alternate method.  Of course, if anyone can point me in a direction to make this functional. I would be happy to stay the course on this.

```
$("#Signup_AgentEmail_T").bind("onFail", function(e, errors)  {

// we are only doing stuff when the form is submitted
if (e.originalEvent.type == 'Keyup') {


        $('#emailDuplicateDialog').dialog('open');  


}
```

});

I created a JSFiddle earlier using the CSS and HTML from the JQueryTools.org example.  The reason for that is because the form on my website is constructed using Active4D and pulls from a 4d database, and not built using HTML.

http://jsfiddle.net/vyJhz/3/

Comment: Can you please share your code? Via jsfiddle or paste it here.

Comment: I posted it into the body.